# "Evolving/Powering Up *Insert Pokemon Here*"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, pokemon

I noticed today that there is a question about evolving or powering up a specific Pokemon, [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277093/should-i-evolve-this-or-power-up). I remember a similar topic came up in Meta around the time of Overwatch's release, in which someone asked if questions about the strengths/weaknesses/synergy of specific heroes were allowed. If I remember correctly, Meta agreed that they were harmless to ask.

As it stands currently, will the site allow questions about specific Pokemon? Whereas in the case of Overwatch, it raises roughly 22 character-based questions. In the case of Pokemon Go, it raises potentially 146 questions (can't count the Mew/Mewtwo/Birds since no one can find them). Would these types of questions lead to repeat answers, or just the same link over and over to a document for all Pokemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer but most of these '*Should I evolve this Pokemon*', '*Which Pokemon should I evolve*' or '*Evolve vs power up*' questions should be marked as a duplicate of the more general [How does evolving relate to CP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274471/28182) and/or [Does it make a difference to CP if you feed candies before or after evolving?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272730/28182), and indeed, a lot of them are.

If you find any more, be diligent in flagging for duplicates.